# Cannot open geojson with leaflet

Tags: mysql, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I am converting my data from database to geojson and then i cant open the returned value from ajax into L.geoJson.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
<link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script
        src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-ajax/2.1.0/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--  Base Map -->
    var map = L.map('map').setView([40.6430126, 22.934004], 14);
    mapLink =
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<script>

      //Ajax
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET", 
            url: "2j.php", 
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function (data) {
            var result = data;

            L.geoJson(result).addTo(map);

        }); 



</script>
```

Php File -> Connection to database and conversation!

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "basi";


$features = array();
$geojson = array(
    'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features'  => $features
 );


$i=1.01;

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Parse the query into geojson 
// ================================================
// ================================================
// Return polygons as GeoJSON

 for($i;$i<10;$i++){
     $k=floor($i);
     $sql = "SELECT x1, y1 FROM afriti where floor(id)=$k";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature', 
      'geometry' => array(
        'type' => 'Polygon',
        'coordinates' => array((float)$row["x1"], (float)$row["y1"])

        ));
    array_push($features, $feature);
       }
     }

 }     echo json_encode($geojson);


?>
```

I tried just to print something after ajax is done and its doesnt output anything, so either its not ending or something is bad written.

It doesnt print any error messages.

Comment: What does the output of 2j.php look like? Is it actually producing the GeoJSON you're expecting?

Comment: Didnt think to do that :) . No , its echoing  {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[]}

Comment: @peeebeee i changed array_push($features,$feature); to array_push($geojson, $feature); and now its echoing the correct data at 2j but still is not displaying the polygons

Comment: OK that's a start. Anything in the JS console in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

For starters you are missing a parenthesis `)` in this line:

```
'coordinates' => array((float)$row["x1"], (float)$row["y1"]));
```